# 2 Where and 1 Group by Condition LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I need to fetch the result of the List by using 2 Where Conditions and GroupBy Condition.

The Query which worked to achive part of the solution is

```
 var errorQuery = AgentOpList.Where(x => x.LastError != "")
                             .GroupBy(x => x.LastError.Substring(0, 30)).ToArray();
```

But now, i should also include another condition in the list, so the condition is
    `x.Status != "FINISHED"`
So the final query which i tried was

```
var errorQuery = AgentOpList.Where(x => x.LastError != "" || x.Status != "FINISHED")
                            .GroupBy(x => x.LastError.Substring(0, 30)).ToArray();
```

However, it throws me the error

> Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter
>   name: length

I know the reason for this error. However, i would like to know the solution.

Comment: What is your input-data? Please provide some sample input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LastError` is shorter than 30 characters.

If you're using linq to objects, you could create a new function:

```
public bool TakeChars(string str, int chars) {
    if (str.Length < 30) { return str; }
    else return str.Substring(0,30);
}
```

And then use it:

```
var errorQuery = AgentOpList.Where(x => x.LastError != "" || x.Status != "FINISHED")
                            .GroupBy(x => TakeChars(x.LastError, 30)).ToArray();
```

If you don't want to create a new function or you're using linq to sql, I think this would work (@FCin):

```
 var errorQuery = AgentOpList.Where(x => x.LastError != "" || x.Status != "FINISHED")
                                .GroupBy(x => x.LastError.Substring(0, Math.Min(30, x.LastError.Length))).ToArray();
```

Also, a small improvement to your `Where`:

```
var errorQuery = AgentOpList.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.LastError) || x.Status != "FINISHED")
                                .GroupBy(x => .... ).ToArray();
```

Comment: How about`str.Substring(0, Math.Min(x.LastError.Length, 30))`?

Comment: @FCin Maybe. What does .Substring do when the final length is the same as the original one? Does it create a new String instance anyway?

Comment: @FCin just checked, it returns the same instance. I'll edit the answer

Comment: It returns the string. It doesn't create a new one. [Proof](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,8124961f027d9ac9)

Comment: @FCin edited. I think this has the added benefit of actually working with Linq to SQL.

Comment: This is the solution which is working...    var errorQuery = AgentOpList.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.LastError) || x.Status != "FINISHED").GroupBy(x => x.LastError.Substring(0, Math.Min(x.LastError.Length, 30))).ToArray();

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `Substring` never receives a string shorter than 30 characters by padding it with trailing spaces:

```
var errorQuery = AgentOpList.Where(x => x.LastError != "" || x.Status != "FINISHED")
   .GroupBy(x => x.LastError.PadRight(30, ' ').Substring(0, 30)).ToArray();
```

(Assuming this is LINQ to objects as SQL's `SUBSTRING` wouldn't throw an exception).